# Improper integral with sine and cosine

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

How does this integral behave with respect to $\alpha$ parameter? $$\int_1^{3/2} \frac{(1-\cos^2(\pi x))^{\alpha}}{\sin(\sqrt{x^2-1})} \ dx$$ I am really unable to say anything constructive about this one..

Comment: What limit are you interested in? $\alpha\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @Jules: Do you mean for which $\alpha$ does the integral converge?

Comment: Yup, for which $\alpha$ it coverges and for which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

First observation is that by changing the variable $t=x-1$ we get 
$$\int_1^{3/2} \frac{(1-\cos^2(\pi x))^{\alpha}}{\sin(\sqrt{x^2-1})} \ dx=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\sin^{2\alpha}(\pi t)}{\sin\left(\sqrt{t(t+2)}\right)}\, dt=\int_0^{1/2}f_\alpha(t)\, dt$$
It is easy to check that $\lim_{t\to0}f_\alpha(t)$ exists iff $\alpha\geq\frac14$.
So, for $\alpha\geq\frac14$ we have a proper integral of a continuous function.

Answer (score 0):

It diverges for $a<0$, and converges otherwise $($in absolute value$)$, being strictly decreasing $($again, in absolute value$)$ for $a\ge0$, due to the fact that the sine function is always $\le1$ in absolute value. Sign-wise, we have negative values for all $a\in\mathbb N$, as well as for rational *a* with odd denominators in simplified form. Otherwise, the values are complex, i.e., when *a* is either irrational, or rational with even denominators in simplified form.

Comment: I don't see how the argument that sine is $\leq 1$ gives me the convergence of this integral. Could you elaborate on that? Sorry I reply so late.

Comment: $0\le|\sin t|\le1=>0^a\le|\sin t|^a\le1^a$, for $a\ge0$. Now, exchange the numerator of your integrand with $0$ and $1$, and if the resulting two integrals are convergent, then the absolute value of your integral is bounded. Furthermore, since $|\sin t|^a$ is strictly decreasing for $a\ge1$, then so is your integral. And if an expression is both bounded and monotonous, then it converges.